# ggplot2 bar chart with rank

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to plot an ordered bar chart using the code below. After plotting I noticed the x-labels have some weird superimposed text at both.  What is the problem and how can fix this. Please see the output and data attached below. Thanks in advance.

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
data <- read_csv("data.csv")
ggplot(data, aes(index_ind, value, fill=index_ind)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$index_ind,labels = data$string)+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WjAibtBnrMezh_WqvlZk6iVmMy3BbsAk/view?usp=sharing)

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDZQ9.png)

Comment: What does "data.csv" look like? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @langtang, I added the data and output to the original post

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your rank variable (`index_ind`) is associated with multiple labels (`string`). Hence, when doing `scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$index_ind,labels = data$string)` multiple labels are plotted at each break or tick.

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `tidytext::reorder_within` and `tidy text::scale_x_reordered` which make it easy to reorder a variable per facet:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(string = reorder_within(string, index_ind, ID))

ggplot(data, aes(string, value, fill = index_ind)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

### DATA

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(
  "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8", "IND12_1", "IND12_2", "IND12_3", "IND12_4",
  "IND14_1", "IND15", "IND2_1", "IND2_2", "IND6_1", "IND6_2", "IND7_1",
  "IND7_2", "IND8"
), variable = c(
  "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100",
  "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100",
  "B100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100",
  "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "O100", "O100",
  "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100",
  "O100", "O100", "O100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100",
  "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100",
  "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100",
  "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100",
  "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100",
  "BDOT100"
), value = c(
  163.1230427, 0.524207523, 3.297149324,
  1.069180266, 1.251679084, 0.927565932, 0.961610773, 1.964142379,
  1.04530503, 1.088576076, 0.799211536, 1.402314597, 0.498908466,
  246.6197702, 0.646352818, 3.747508064, 1.088011403, 1.180427503,
  0.959425429, 0.972116213, 1.645477704, 1.037632886, 1.097167994,
  0.802213356, 1.107660179, 0.464610157, 49.89298674, 0.513891234,
  3.957970236, 1.059717335, 7.974913576, 0.937470008, 0.962981204,
  1.902443191, 1.057828336, 1.127642548, 0.68902783, 1.177413236,
  0.419146527, 48.18264836, 0.583902859, 3.712832105, 1.068303635,
  1.187917424, 0.958630088, 0.971798954, 1.654296544, 1.032098493,
  1.077685273, 0.801367013, 1.160393815, 0.462143374, 135.7710367,
  0.622287138, 3.697980818, 1.074982985, 1.184846803, 0.958256969,
  0.971559456, 1.661787996, 1.032871856, 1.084851996, 0.795942373,
  1.123137113, 0.462381347, 205.9875701, 0.731107815, 2.912218507,
  1.122934691, 1.170463689, 0.956944718, 0.981670211, 1.399917522,
  1.030668427, 1.068595276, 0.981213768, 1.177096757, 0.555469198,
  181.2865963, 0.760306941, 2.646478074, 1.10566832, 1.22723098,
  0.956399596, 0.981351766, 1.408012251, 1.029716395, 1.063546348,
  0.984395095, 1.190972441, 0.560190343
), index_ind = c(
  4, 2, 3,
  3, 6, 1, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 2, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5,
  1, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 7, 2, 2, 6, 7, 7, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6,
  4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6,
  6, 2, 7, 1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 6, 5, 7, 1, 6, 5, 3, 6, 2, 1,
  1, 7, 6, 7
), string = c(
  "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100",
  "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100", "B100",
  "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100",
  "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "D100", "O100", "O100", "O100",
  "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100", "O100",
  "O100", "O100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100",
  "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "T100", "DOT100",
  "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100",
  "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "DOT100", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt", "BDOT_opt",
  "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100",
  "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100", "BDOT100",
  "BDOT100"
)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), variable = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), value = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), index_ind = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), string = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  ))
), default = structure(list(), class = c(
  "collector_guess",
  "collector"
)), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```